# Colima "pull access denied" for ECR repositories

Tags: docker, amazon-ecr, colima

I am just starting out with colima and works great for one of my projects, however for a project that uses a private ECR repository I am getting a `pull access denied` error. I am making sure to login using:

```
aws --profile=PROFILE ecr get-login-password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin ACCOUNT_NUMBER.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

My `~/.docker/config.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "auths": {
        "ACCOUNT_NUMBER.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com": {}
    },
    "credsStore": "osxkeychain",
    "currentContext": "colima"
}
```

I also tried the setting with and without the `credStore` entry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the ecr-credential-helper https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-ecr-credential-helper and modifying my docker config to something to include the following worked. See the GH answer here: https://github.com/abiosoft/colima/discussions/647

```
{
  "credHelpers": {
    "public.ecr.aws": "ecr-login",
    "<AWS_ACCOUNT_ID>.dkr.ecr.<REGION>.amazonaws.com": "ecr-login"
  }
}
```